# Jacobi Triple Product using Euler's identities

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, theta-functions

I recently came across a simple proof for Jacobi's triple product ([here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-02/S0002-9939-1965-0171725-X/S0002-9939-1965-0171725-X.pdf)), in the proof Andrews assumes two identities:

$$
E_1 = \prod_{n=0}^{\infty}(1+x^nz) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n(n-1)/2}z^n}{(1-x)...(1-x^n)}
$$
and
$$
E_2 = \prod_{n=0}^{\infty}(1+x^nz)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nz^n}{(1-x)...(1-x^n)}
$$

While the proof itself is well written and easy to understand, I can't find a proof of the two identities given in the paper, mostly because their names is not stated and the reference is from a book I can't find online.

Would anyone be able to give a short proof or redirect me to a proof of those two identities?

Thank you

Comment: Jacobi's original proof is also based on the first identity. Search "triple product" in https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/02/elliptic-functions-theta-functions-contd.html?m=0 for Jacobi's proof.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a combinatorial interpretation for these identities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92619/is-there-a-combinatorial-interpretation-for-these-identities)

Answer (score 1):

These identities are pretty standard. Let's write $$F(x, z)=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty} (1+x^nz)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n\tag{1}$$ We can see that $F$ satisfies functional equation $$F(x, z) =(1+z) F(x, zx)\tag{2} $$ and using the infinite series for $F$ in above equation we get $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n=(1+z)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^nz^n$$ Equating coefficients of $z^n$ on both sides we get $$a_n=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$$ or $$a_n=\frac{x^{n-1}}{1-x^n}a_{n-1}$$ Using this equation recursively and noting that $a_0=1$ we get $$a_n=\frac{x^{n(n-1)/2}}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\dots(1-x^n)}$$ and the first identity in question is proved. The second identity can be established in similar manner.